# Reset Daterangepicker to initial values

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I have a dropdown [daterange](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) picker which has calendar and time ranges that can be selected. Once I click, I set the values. Now how do I reset the form to initial state. Is there a single line like `$(".daterangepicker").reset()` to reset the entire calendar. Didn't find any examples relating to it in the website.

Comment: As far as I read, there is no such method in the plugin. A workaround would be to use a custom function to reset the fields, and maybe use .attr if you can't store the default/initial values

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.daterangepicker .cancelBtn').click();
```

Programmatically clicking the **Clear** button invokes the `clickCancel` method.

*Excerpt from daterangepicker.js:*

```
clickCancel: function(e) {
    this.startDate = this.oldStartDate;
    this.endDate = this.oldEndDate;
    this.hide();
    this.element.trigger('cancel.daterangepicker', this);
},
```

Using daterangepicker v3.0.5

Answer (score 1):

Today I was dealing with the same problem and found a solution. if you are looking to reset daterangepicker from outside button click, use the below one magical line on button on-click event. This will reset the daterangepicker to its initial state.

```
$('.daterangepicker .cancelBtn').trigger('click');
```